# Core data one to many relationships: fetching specific related entities

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I have 2 entities: `Train` and `Station`

Each train stops at multiple stations, i.e. `Train <--->> Station`.
The list of stations a train stops at is different from the list of stations some other train stops at.

How do I correctly save and fetch the list of stations for a particular train?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this:

```
Train <--->> Station
```

mean you have a one to many relationship?  If so, it doesn't work, unless only one train can stop at each station.  What I would do is create a third entity, call it say "stop" with two relations, a many to one to `Train` and a many to one to `Station`.  It wil look something like

```
+-----+       +-------+
|Train|       |Stop   |        +-------+
+-----+       +-------+        |Station|
|stops|<---->>|train  |        +-------+
+-----+       |station|<<----->|stops  |
              +-------+        +-------+
```

To find all the stations a particular train stops at, just look at the `stops` property of the `Train` which will be an `NSSet` of `Stop` objects each of which has a property which is a station the train stops at.

To add new stops, just create a new `Stop` object and set its `train` and `station` properties appropriately.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This makes a lot of sense. A quick question -- there are arrival and departure times for each station (which of course will be different for different trains). So should these attributes be added in the 'Stop' entity?

Comment: @CodeBreaker:  yes.  In fact, I was going to make a suggestion about that in my answer, but I forgot.

Comment: Seems good explanation but still its not penetrating in my mind. Will have a cup of tea and try to grasp it again. If unsuccessful I will ask question.. :-D