# How to fetch Specific Data in One to Many Core Data Relationships?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have made one sample demo on core data relationships.I have one Table "User" which is connected another table "Account" In form of "One to Many" relation.

## Code

```
-(IBAction)savePersonData:(id)sender
{

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;

    NSManagedObject *newDevice = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [newDevice setValue:self.personName.text forKey:@"name"];
    [newDevice setValue:self.personAddress.text forKey:@"address"];
    [newDevice setValue:self.personMobileNo.text forKey:@"mobile_no"];


    NSManagedObject *newAccount = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Account" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [newAccount setValue:self.accountNo.text forKey:@"acc_no"];
    [newAccount setValue:self.accountType.text forKey:@"acc_type"];
    [newAccount setValue:self.balance.text forKey:@"balance"];

    NSLog(@"Saved Successfully");
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

## Image is

## My Question is

I have find so many time but could not find proper answer.So I post this question second time.

My question is I have insert Manually Three person With their Account's Details.

Now ,I Want A balance which I have entered for specific person when I enter Mobile number.

## Ex

1)Enter 1st Mobile Num. Should be display first Person's Balance.
2)Enter 2nd Mobile Num. Should be display second Person's Balance.
1)Enter 3rd Mobile Num. Should be display third Person's Balance.

## Balance Check Code

```
-(IBAction)checkBalance:(id)sender

{ NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Person"];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"mobile_no = %@",self.textField.text];

    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *result = [appDelegate.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    if(!([result count] == 0))
    {        

        NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
        NSFetchRequest *newFetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Account"];
        NSMutableArray *temp = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:newFetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

        for (NSManagedObject *object in temp)
        {
            NSString *intValue = [object valueForKey:@"balance"];
            NSString *alertString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",intValue];
            [self displayAlertView:@"Available Balance" withMessage:alertString];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        [self displayAlertView:@"Error" withMessage:@"Please Enter Valid Mobile Number That you have entered in Bank"];
    }
}
```

## Images

[image]

## Output

[image]
[image]

I want Balance With Specific Person Which I enter Person Mobile No on TextField.

Sorry Guys,I have asked second time ,But Could no able to solve this core data relationships.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you check that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20157803/display-core-data-entity-records-with-relationship-1m?rq=1 and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8310652/core-data-one-to-many-relationships-fetching-specific-related-entities?rq=1

Comment: I have already checked those two link.Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Match object value of NSSet in CoreData?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41372977/how-to-match-object-value-of-nsset-in-coredata)

Comment: Buddy you are right this is right but whatever you answered that only matching phone number nothing more...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First...**

Fix the naming of your relationships.  As others have pointed out in comments on your other question, you have named them back to front: in the `Person` entity, the to-many relationship to `Account` should be named "accounts" not "person".  Likewise in the `Account` entity, the to-one relationship to `Person` should be named "person" not "accounts".

**Next...**

Although you have defined the "accounts" relationship as to-many, the `savePersonData` code in this question creates only one `Account` and one `Person` - but does not then set the relationship between them.  (You can see this in your Output: each `Account` has nil for its "accounts" relationship).

The code in your previous question did set the relationship (by adding the `newAccount` to the relationship on the `newPerson` object).  In your code above you could use (after fixing the relationship names):

```
NSMutableSet *setContainer = [newDevice mutableSetValueForKey:@"accounts"];
[setContainer addObject:newAccount];
```

but with one-many relationships it is easier to set the inverse relationship:

```
[newAccount setValue:newDevice forKey:@"person"];
```

**Next...**

Your `checkBalance` method correctly fetches any `Person` objects whose "mobile_no" attribute matches.  But your subsequent code then fetches ALL `Account` objects - even if you had correctly set the relationship.

If you want only those `Account` objects that are related to a given `Person`, that is precisely what the "accounts" relationship represents.  So you could just use that relationship to access the related `Account` objects:

```
if(!([result count] == 0)) {
    NSManagedObject *requiredPerson = (NSManagedObject *)result[0];
    NSSet *temp = [requiredPerson valueForKey:@"accounts"];
    for (NSManagedObject *object in temp) {
        NSString *intValue = [object valueForKey:@"balance"];
        NSString *alertString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",intValue];
        [self displayAlertView:@"Available Balance" withMessage:alertString];
    }
}
```

Alternatively, fetch the relevant `Account` objects directly (without fetching the `Person` object first) by specifying a predicate that traverses the relationship:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
NSFetchRequest *newFetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Account"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"person.mobile_no = %@",self.textField.text];
[newFetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

NSMutableArray *temp = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:newFetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

    for (NSManagedObject *object in temp)
    {
        NSString *intValue = [object valueForKey:@"balance"];
        NSString *alertString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",intValue];
        [self displayAlertView:@"Available Balance" withMessage:alertString];
    }
```

Comment: Thank You So much working perfectly.Thanks a lot pbasdf.